# add a date range to pandas dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
id   a  b
01   1  2
01   3  4
02   5  6
03   7  8
```

I have a dataframe that I would like to add a date range to grouped by ID, the result should look like this

```
id   a  b  date
01   1  2  31/03/2021
01   3  4  30/04/2021
02   5  6  31/03/2021
03   7  8  31/03/2021
```

but i actually just need the last day of each month for my calc like this

```
id   a  b  day
01   1  2  31
01   3  4  30
02   5  6  31
03   7  8  31
```

Comment: what is logic for add column `date` ?

Comment: I am doing a bunch of financial calculations on large data, and I just need to add a date column to my data ,sort of like a forecast month column, but I only need the last day of each forecast month to perform the next calculation

Comment: so you arbitrarily set the initial date?

Comment: yes thats correct , the first date is the first forecast month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can apply a `date_range` per group:

```
start = '2021-03-31'

df['date'] = (df
              .groupby('id')
              .apply(lambda g: pd.date_range(start=start, periods=len(g), freq='M').to_series())
              .values)
```

output:

```
   id  a  b       date
0   1  1  2 2021-03-31
1   1  3  4 2021-04-30
2   2  5  6 2021-03-31
3   3  7  8 2021-03-31
```

or, for the day:

```
start = '2021-03-31'

df['date'] = (df
              .groupby('id')
              .apply(lambda g: pd.date_range(start=start, periods=len(g), freq='M').to_series())
              .dt.day
              .values
             )
```

output:

```
   id  a  b  date
0   1  1  2    31
1   1  3  4    30
2   2  5  6    31
3   3  7  8    31
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and add months by [`offsets.MonthOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset.html) with add to strating datetime, last use [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2021-03-31')
df['day'] = (start + df.groupby('id').cumcount()
                      .apply(lambda x: pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x))).dt.day

print (df)
   id  a  b  day
0   1  1  2   31
1   1  3  4   30
2   2  5  6   31
3   3  7  8   31
```

Alternative is create moth periods in numpy with [`Series.dt.days_in_month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days_in_month.html):

```
start = pd.to_datetime(['2021-03-31']).to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
df['day'] = (start + np.array(df.groupby('id').cumcount(), dtype='timedelta64[M]'))
df['day'] = df['day'].dt.days_in_month

print (df)
   id  a  b  day
0   1  1  2   31
1   1  3  4   30
2   2  5  6   31
3   3  7  8   31
```

Comment: this doesn't look like the correct output